# Multiple commands in sudo over ssh in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sudo

My script is as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

version = 1.1

echo "Enter username"

read UserName

ssh -t $UserName@server bash -c " '

./runSomeScript

echo "Entering Sudo"

sudo -s -u user1 -c "cd random; ./randomscrip xx-$version-yy"

'"
```

---

But this is not working.

Basically i want to do a ssh to a account. And then runSomeScript
Then do a sudo with user as user1 and then run commands cd random and ./randomscrip (with xx-Version-yy as argument) as the sudo user only.
But the commands inside sudo are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting is a little careless. You're using double-quotes for the first and third levels of quoting, and the shell can't tell one from the other. Do something like this instead:

```
sudoScript="cd random; ./randomscrip xx-${version}-yy"
sshScript='
  ./runSomeScript
  echo "Entering Sudo"
  sudo -s -u user1 bash -c '"'${sudoScript}'"'
'
ssh -t ${UserName}@server "${sshScript}"
```

But beware that if you embed any single-quotes, it will still go wrong unless you add a layer of shell-quoting.

Finally, remove the spaces around `=` when you assign to `version`.

Comment: Not working, commands in sudoScript fails. Commands in sudoScript runs in ssh session instead of running in sudo mode.

Comment: @A.G. You're right. It seems sudo -s doesn't really run the command in a shell as the man page promised. I've edited it and tested it to make sure it works.